# Why does "Look Up" on iOS briefly flash and image?

Tags: ios, bug, siri

When I use "Look Up" on iOS, I briefly see an image flash, which then vanishes:

[image]

I've had this behavior for several iOS upgrades, and through two hardware changes.

I assume the image is supposed to remain visible. Why is this happening and how do I prevent it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in earlier versions of iOS, fixed on 17.1.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that is a caching issue of some sort. The image (sourced from Wikipedia default article image) is still publically accessible.

Might I ask if you're approaching full storage on this phone? Also, that wouldn't be the most surprising if you were running a beta.

I happen to be running beta iOS 16 on a 13 Pro Max, though the image loaded for me on the same search term "Pantolambda".

[image: Pantolambda Lookup Menu on iOS and MacOS]

Hate to be the person to recommend this step, but a reset might help with odd UI bugs like that if all else fails.

Comment: Sorry maybe it wasn't clear: this always happens, so caching is not likely. It also happens regardless of what network I'm using, so it's not blocking or filtering (and of course I do see the image briefly, so it's getting through.) and I don't think a reset (which I'm not doing anyway) is going to help: this has persisted through hardware upgrades.